# /etc/hosts file setting for no dns lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, hosts

Can you explain me what I need to add in my hosts file for no dns look up

Comment: Please specify your OS. This question is highly OS-specific.

Answer (score 5):

> Can you explain me what I need to add
>   in my hosts file for no dns look up

That is the wrong question to ask. The hosts file does not control whether or not DNS lookups are performed; it just provides a way to obtain IP addresses w/o DNS.

To control lookup behaviour, you need to modify `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (at least on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

The file you need is [host.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/host.conf), this configures the DNS resolver for the system. To disable external DNS lookups and to use only the hosts file use:

order hosts

In addition, depending on the distribution, you may need to edit [nsswitch.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf) as well.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to just create an empty /etc/resolv.conf if you want to stop DNS lookups from working.